# SVG Animation only working correctly in Firefox

Tags: svg

I'm new to SVG and I'm wondering why my animation is only working in Firefox (I'm using 9.0.1).

Safari and Opera seem to display it incorrectly.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with my code or if it's a browser issue.  Any help or advice to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
<style type='text/css'>
<![CDATA[
rect {
fill: white;
}

line { 
stroke: black;
stroke-width: 1px;
}

]]>
</style>
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" />
<svg y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
<line x1="0.81%" y1="49.80%" x2="0.81%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="1.63%" y1="45.49%" x2="1.63%" y2="54.51%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="2.44%" y1="7.84%" x2="2.44%" y2="92.16%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="3.25%" y1="55.69%" x2="3.25%" y2="44.31%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="4.07%" y1="44.31%" x2="4.07%" y2="55.69%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="4.88%" y1="33.33%" x2="4.88%" y2="66.67%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="5.69%" y1="65.10%" x2="5.69%" y2="34.9%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="6.50%" y1="64.71%" x2="6.50%" y2="35.29%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="7.32%" y1="43.92%" x2="7.32%" y2="56.08%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="8.13%" y1="30.98%" x2="8.13%" y2="69.02%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="8.94%" y1="45.49%" x2="8.94%" y2="54.51%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="9.76%" y1="66.27%" x2="9.76%" y2="33.73%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="10.57%" y1="63.14%" x2="10.57%" y2="36.86%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="11.38%" y1="53.73%" x2="11.38%" y2="46.27%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="12.20%" y1="38.43%" x2="12.20%" y2="61.57%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="13.01%" y1="30.20%" x2="13.01%" y2="69.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="13.82%" y1="44.31%" x2="13.82%" y2="55.69%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="14.63%" y1="60.00%" x2="14.63%" y2="40%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="15.45%" y1="68.24%" x2="15.45%" y2="31.76%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="16.26%" y1="62.75%" x2="16.26%" y2="37.25%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="17.07%" y1="48.63%" x2="17.07%" y2="51.37%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="17.89%" y1="38.43%" x2="17.89%" y2="61.57%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="18.70%" y1="36.08%" x2="18.70%" y2="63.92%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="19.51%" y1="39.22%" x2="19.51%" y2="60.78%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="20.33%" y1="49.41%" x2="20.33%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="21.14%" y1="60.39%" x2="21.14%" y2="39.61%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="21.95%" y1="63.92%" x2="21.95%" y2="36.08%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="22.76%" y1="57.25%" x2="22.76%" y2="42.75%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="23.58%" y1="51.76%" x2="23.58%" y2="48.24%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="24.39%" y1="49.80%" x2="24.39%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="25.20%" y1="42.35%" x2="25.20%" y2="57.65%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="26.02%" y1="38.82%" x2="26.02%" y2="61.18%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="26.83%" y1="41.18%" x2="26.83%" y2="58.82%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="27.64%" y1="49.02%" x2="27.64%" y2="50.98%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="28.46%" y1="53.33%" x2="28.46%" y2="46.67%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="29.27%" y1="58.04%" x2="29.27%" y2="41.96%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="30.08%" y1="60.78%" x2="30.08%" y2="39.22%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="30.89%" y1="57.65%" x2="30.89%" y2="42.35%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="31.71%" y1="51.37%" x2="31.71%" y2="48.63%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="32.52%" y1="43.92%" x2="32.52%" y2="56.08%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="33.33%" y1="41.96%" x2="33.33%" y2="58.04%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="34.15%" y1="44.31%" x2="34.15%" y2="55.69%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="34.96%" y1="45.10%" x2="34.96%" y2="54.9%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="35.77%" y1="46.27%" x2="35.77%" y2="53.73%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="36.59%" y1="52.16%" x2="36.59%" y2="47.84%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="37.40%" y1="55.69%" x2="37.40%" y2="44.31%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="38.21%" y1="54.51%" x2="38.21%" y2="45.49%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="39.02%" y1="54.51%" x2="39.02%" y2="45.49%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="39.84%" y1="54.51%" x2="39.84%" y2="45.49%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="40.65%" y1="52.16%" x2="40.65%" y2="47.84%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="41.46%" y1="47.84%" x2="41.46%" y2="52.16%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="42.28%" y1="44.31%" x2="42.28%" y2="55.69%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="43.09%" y1="43.92%" x2="43.09%" y2="56.08%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="43.90%" y1="46.67%" x2="43.90%" y2="53.33%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="44.72%" y1="49.02%" x2="44.72%" y2="50.98%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="45.53%" y1="52.55%" x2="45.53%" y2="47.45%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="46.34%" y1="53.33%" x2="46.34%" y2="46.67%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="47.15%" y1="52.55%" x2="47.15%" y2="47.45%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="47.97%" y1="50.98%" x2="47.97%" y2="49.02%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="48.78%" y1="50.20%" x2="48.78%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="49.59%" y1="49.41%" x2="49.59%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="50.41%" y1="46.67%" x2="50.41%" y2="53.33%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="51.22%" y1="47.45%" x2="51.22%" y2="52.55%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="52.03%" y1="49.02%" x2="52.03%" y2="50.98%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="52.85%" y1="50.59%" x2="52.85%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="53.66%" y1="50.20%" x2="53.66%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="54.47%" y1="49.02%" x2="54.47%" y2="50.98%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="55.28%" y1="50.59%" x2="55.28%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="56.10%" y1="50.59%" x2="56.10%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="56.91%" y1="49.41%" x2="56.91%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="57.72%" y1="47.84%" x2="57.72%" y2="52.16%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="58.54%" y1="48.24%" x2="58.54%" y2="51.76%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="59.35%" y1="48.63%" x2="59.35%" y2="51.37%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="60.16%" y1="50.20%" x2="60.16%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="60.98%" y1="51.37%" x2="60.98%" y2="48.63%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="61.79%" y1="52.16%" x2="61.79%" y2="47.84%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="62.60%" y1="51.76%" x2="62.60%" y2="48.24%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="63.41%" y1="51.37%" x2="63.41%" y2="48.63%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="64.23%" y1="50.59%" x2="64.23%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="65.04%" y1="50.98%" x2="65.04%" y2="49.02%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="65.85%" y1="49.41%" x2="65.85%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="66.67%" y1="48.24%" x2="66.67%" y2="51.76%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="67.48%" y1="47.84%" x2="67.48%" y2="52.16%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="68.29%" y1="48.63%" x2="68.29%" y2="51.37%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="69.11%" y1="49.41%" x2="69.11%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="69.92%" y1="49.80%" x2="69.92%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="70.73%" y1="49.80%" x2="70.73%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="71.54%" y1="50.98%" x2="71.54%" y2="49.02%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="72.36%" y1="51.76%" x2="72.36%" y2="48.24%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="73.17%" y1="51.37%" x2="73.17%" y2="48.63%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="73.98%" y1="50.98%" x2="73.98%" y2="49.02%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="74.80%" y1="51.37%" x2="74.80%" y2="48.63%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="75.61%" y1="50.20%" x2="75.61%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="76.42%" y1="50.20%" x2="76.42%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="77.24%" y1="50.20%" x2="77.24%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="78.05%" y1="49.80%" x2="78.05%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="78.86%" y1="48.63%" x2="78.86%" y2="51.37%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="79.67%" y1="48.63%" x2="79.67%" y2="51.37%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="80.49%" y1="49.80%" x2="80.49%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="81.30%" y1="49.80%" x2="81.30%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="82.11%" y1="49.41%" x2="82.11%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="82.93%" y1="49.41%" x2="82.93%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="83.74%" y1="49.41%" x2="83.74%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="84.55%" y1="50.20%" x2="84.55%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="85.37%" y1="50.20%" x2="85.37%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="86.18%" y1="49.80%" x2="86.18%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="86.99%" y1="50.20%" x2="86.99%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="87.80%" y1="50.59%" x2="87.80%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="88.62%" y1="50.59%" x2="88.62%" y2="49.41%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="89.43%" y1="49.80%" x2="89.43%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="90.24%" y1="49.41%" x2="90.24%" y2="50.59%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="91.06%" y1="50.20%" x2="91.06%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />

<line x1="91.87%" y1="49.80%" x2="91.87%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="92.68%" y1="49.80%" x2="92.68%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="93.50%" y1="49.80%" x2="93.50%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="94.31%" y1="50.20%" x2="94.31%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="95.12%" y1="50.20%" x2="95.12%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="95.93%" y1="49.80%" x2="95.93%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="96.75%" y1="50.20%" x2="96.75%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="97.56%" y1="50.20%" x2="97.56%" y2="49.8%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="98.37%" y1="49.80%" x2="98.37%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="99.19%" y1="49.80%" x2="99.19%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
<line x1="100.00%" y1="49.80%" x2="100.00%" y2="50.2%" style='stroke-width: 1;' />
</svg>

<svg y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
<rect x='0' y='0' height='100%' width='100%' />
<animate attributeName='x' from='0' to='100%' dur='1s' fill='freeze' />
<line x1='0' y1='50%' x2='5' y2='50%' style='stroke-width: 10; stroke: red;' />

</svg>

</svg>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Safari issue**

There's alot of pitfalls to avoid compared to other browsers. The easiest way I've come up with for satisfying results is to embed the SVG file inside HTML like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="mySvgFile.svg" width="100%"/>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are serving pure SVG files (i.e. not wrapped in HTML) you must configure your server to serve the files with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` or `Content-Type: image/svg+xml`. I've never done this part myself, only watched how others do it and they both seem to work.

SVG inline with HTML won't run animations.

**Precautions**

I've run into problems when using single quotes instead of doubles and also when not setting the width and height of the top SVG element. Perhaps it will work anyway, but best to stay on the safe side.

**Core problem**

If we reduce your code to the core problem we end up with this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FrNrW/

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  width="100%"
  height="100%">

  <svg x="0" y="0">
    <animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="100%" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="5" y2="50%" stroke-width="10" stroke="red"/>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Apparently, `animate` doesn't play nice with `svg` in webkit. This will work instead:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PtPCX/

```
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  width="100%"
  height="150"
  viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  preserveAspectRatio="none">

  <g>
    <animateMotion path="M0,0 H100" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2=".5" y2="50%" stroke-width="5" stroke="red"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

The workaround is switching `svg` => `g` and `animation` => `animationMotion`. `animateMotion` requires a path and paths can't contain percentage values, so add a `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` attribute to the top svg element. Now ALL values will work like percentage values even if leave out `%`. Also add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, this ruins the proportions but makes the svg fill the screen.

**Finally**

Now, just paste in the rest of your original code and change the `height` and `stroke-width` appropriately.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ypqVx/

Comment: It's a browser issue. That said, both your code and @bennedich's [simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/FrNrW/) work just fine in [the current WebKit nightly](http://nightly.webkit.org/), and this improvement should be migrating to a Browser Near You™ in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I am trying use the SVG animation inline with HTML using the object or embed tag.  Ideally, I'd like it to animate as a background image that scales to full browser width/height.  I may need to find another method of achieving this effect since it's a browser issue.

Comment: With inline I meant if you put svg elements immediately in the HTML. If you embed with embed/img/object you're safe, no need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<animate attributeName='x' from='0' to='100%' dur='1s' fill='freeze' />
```

To:

```
<animate attributeName='x' from='0%' to='100%' dur='1s' fill='freeze' />
```

That makes it work in Opera.